# Start Domino service and word

Tags: windows, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I want to modify a word document from an agent in Lotus Script. Domino server starts as a service with an Administrator user count. The word document is attached in a Lotus Notes document. I extract the document in a folder that Domino has access. 
When the Domino server (as service) runs the process, the Domino displays an error. But when I start the Domino server as application, the process runs well and it doesn't get any error.
The script code is the next:

```
Set rtItem = doc_perfil.GetFirstItem(campo)
Set obj = rtitem.EmbeddedObjects(0) 
sFile = RUTA + "\" + ReplaceSubstring(nameNewFile, "/", "-") + ".docx"
Call obj.ExtractFile(sFile)
OLE_OBJECT = "word.application"     
Set Word = CreateObject (OLE_OBJECT)
Set templt = Word.Documents.Add (sFile)
```

The line that produces the error is "**Set templt = Word.Documents.Add (sFile)**"

Comment: When you run the Domino as a regular application, do you see any UI activity when you run the agent? If I recall correctly, all modern Windows Server versions have a security feature that prevents services from accessing the UI. Since OLE classes actually launch applications and send automation commends (as opposed to COM classes, that provide direct access to application features), they are affected by this restriction. What I don't recall is if there is any way to override this.

Comment: I guess that the variable RUTA holds a path to a network location... unfortunately Windows Services don't have network credentials... and if they do: the network drive will not be mapped in that special context, even if it is in the logged in session... try with a local path instead to find out, if this is the problem. This or the "UI"- Problem that Richard mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried to run the domino under a service account (not localSystem)?

Answer (score 1):

As a first point, running Word on a server is totally unsupported by Microsoft.

The quick and dirty way round this is to not run Domino as a service.  A service can't interact with the UI which it needs to for OLE.

The downside to this is that the Domino Server will need to be manually restarted if the Windows server ever reboots.

The proper way to do this is to do what you need in java using a library like docx4j or Apache POI.  As you don't include any code beyond opening the word doc, I can't comment further on what would be a suitable library.

Answer (score 0):

In the line of code,
Set templt = Word.Documents.Add (sFile)
Add, does not take parameters, please try word.documents.open

If the Domino is not run as a service and still the error occurs, change the security level of the agent to 3 (run will full admin rights)